# How to show the log file content in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar, logfile

Inside my shiny app I'm compiling a python script which generate the result and a log file which shows the progress.

```
create_file <- reactive({

  tmpDir <- tempdir() 
  file1 = as.integer(Sys.time())
  file_name = file.path(tmpDir,paste0(file1,".txt") )
  file_name1 = file.path(tmpDir,paste0(file1,".out") )

  sink(file_name,append = TRUE)
  print(mydata)
  sink()

  ##### progress bar ###########
  progress <- shiny::Progress$new()
  on.exit(progress$close())
  progress$set(message = " calculating ... ", value = 0)

  system(paste("python code.py -s",file_name,"-d db.xml"))

  progress$inc()
  result = list(file_name1 = file_name1,tmpDir = tmpDir)
  return(result)

})

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function() {"lrm.txt"},
  content = function(file) {
    file.copy(create_file()$file_name1, file) 

  }
)
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
  unlink(create_file()$tmpDir, recursive = T)
})
```

Since the calculation is time-consuming I would like to show the progress by showing the last line of the log file, that user see the progress.

But I do not know how to do that ?!
the log file name will be `file1.log`.

Comment: Where should the line be printed, to the console or interface?

Comment: @Chabo, Interface of course .

Comment: see https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson4/

Comment: @Chabo ???? so what ?!!!! Totaly irelevant !!!

Comment: Listen here, no one is entitled to help you so relax. Now, that article outlines how to display a reactive output, an output that changes. Since you are displaying the last line of a continually updated log file, we would consider your output to be reactive, meaning it needs to change. That irrelevant article explains how to do so.

Comment: @Chabo, You don't have to answer when you don't have the knowledge  ! I know how to work with reactive function and display reactive output ! you should probably read the question more carefully .

Comment: @user9112767 you could use `invalidateLater` function. to repeat showing the last line of the log file over and over again